# How can I do Magento one page checkout (together with the UI) using API calls?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I want to implement one page checkout part of Magento from the outside of Magento structure (i.e. using API calls). If it is possible, I want to start using the existing code to reduce the implementation effort. So, how can I modify the existing checkout implementation in order to make it run from outside? Or, is there any other implementation which provides Magento checkout functionality together with the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it is your after but if you're thinking of using Magento checkout say in Wordpress then you could simply include app/Mage.php and use pretty much all the functionality provided by Magento.

Say create a product (you would need one to check out) on the fly if it isn't already in Magento or render any templates - checkout in your case.

Not a problem to insert "add to cart" buttons to any website and use AJAX to request cart contents to the same page.

Also I just needed to code pretty much the same thing for OneStepCheckout which opens up in lightbox and allows you to check out from pretty much anywhere. HTML onepager for example or from Facebook:P